# How to scale down a header at a certain resolution?

Tags: html, css

I’m stuck in designing a header. The header design is right now a grey bar at the top of the screen at which the logo is located at the left of the screen and all header buttons are located at the right. The header buttons will slide to the left.

The issue is the logo and header will overlap at a certain resolution. What I want to accomplish is making it so the header buttons don’t move anymore at a starting width of 1280px. Starting from the width of 1280px and less I want the header to start shrinking.

Is there any way I can do this with declarations in CSS? If not, how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [css media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), in which you can set different style rules for different resolution which will possibly solve the header buttons issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to acheive it by using @media in css. you can define the same css class to have different affects for different width, such as:

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  .header-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can find more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries